# How to do Junit Test with Google Cloud Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using push pub/sub of Google Cloud Pub/Sub in my system,and I want to build my CI test code but I don't know how to do it.For example,some codes are like this:

```
final Pubsub pubsub = PubsubUtils.getClient();
final PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = new PubsubMessage();

pubsubMessage.encodeData(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
Map<String, String> attrs = new HashMap<String, String>();
attrs.put("key", "value");
pubsubMessage.setAttributes(attrs);

final List<PubsubMessage> messages = ImmutableList.of(pubsubMessage);
final PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest().setMessages(messages);
        final PublishResponse publishResponse = pubsub.projects().topics().publish(topic, publishRequest).execute();
        final List<String> messageIds = publishResponse.getMessageIds();
```

and this:

```
final ServletInputStream reader = request.getInputStream();
        try {
            // Parse the JSON message to the POJO model class.
            final JsonParser parser = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance().createJsonParser(reader);

            parser.skipToKey("message");

            final PubsubMessage message = parser.parseAndClose(PubsubMessage.class);

            Map<String, String> attrs = message.getAttributes();
            String value = attrs.get("key");

            // Base64-decode the data and work with it.
            final String data = new String(message.decodeData(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            if (data != null || StringUtils.isNotEmpty(data)) {
                Logger.getLogger("logger").info(data);
            }
            // Work with your message
            // Respond with a 20X to acknowledge receipt of the message.
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
```

How to write a normally Junit test case for the two parts of code? and also,I'm using PowerMockito to mock the objects.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For unit testing the first example, you can mock the Pub/Sub client object with desired return values for API calls like:

```java
import com.google.api.services.pubsub.Pubsub;
import com.google.api.services.pubsub.Pubsub.Projects;
import com.google.api.services.pubsub.Pubsub.Projects.Topics;
import com.google.api.services.pubsub.Pubsub.Projects.Topics.Create;
import com.google.api.services.pubsub.Pubsub.Projects.Topics.Publish;
// ...
@Mock private Pubsub mockPubsub;
@Mock private Projects mockProjects;
@Mock private Topics mockTopics;
@Mock private Create mockCreate;
@Mock private Publish mockPublish;
// ...
String topicName = "projects/myproject/topics/mytopic";
String messageId = "messageId";
List<String> messageIds = ImmutableList.of(messageId);
PublishResponse publishResponse = new PublishResponse()
        .setMessageIds(messageIds);

when(mockPubsub.projects()).thenReturn(mockProjects);
when(mockProjects.topics()).thenReturn(mockTopics);
when(mockTopics.publish(eq(topicName), isA(PublishRequest.class)))
        .thenReturn(mockPublish);
when(mockPublish.execute()).thenReturn(publishResponse);
```

For the second example, you can mock the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` then call the servlet with these mock objects.

Comment: Yes,I have done the second example,and the first example is on going.

Comment: I think the first example may works fine.thank you !